# Fetching the title of top searched result in PHP & mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am having a table named `tb_search_report` which contains the fields `search_report_id`,`sales_id`,`cat_name`,`search_keyword`. My purpose is to create a list in the admin side of my website to get the list of the keywords used to search in the front end as well as the count of those keywords. 
For that i used the following query:-

```
SELECT search_keyword,
    cat_name,
    COUNT(search_keyword) AS cnt 
FROM tb_search_report GROUP BY search_keyword
```

The result is as follows,

```
search_keyword |cat_name |  cnt
------------------------------------
NULL       |Handbags |  6
Shoes          |         |  1
Fabrics        |         |  3
```

Now i need to get/list the top search results viewed in the front end along with the above table in another column. The search listing comes from `tbl_sales` whose primary key is `sales_id`. How can i display the names of the sales `sales_title` in top search sales from search keyword. Need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables so that you can show the sales_title

```
SELECT tbl_sales.sales_title,tb_search_report.search_keyword,tb_search_report.cat_name,
COUNT(tb_search_report.search_keyword) AS cnt
FROM tb_search_report
INNER JOIN tbl_sales ON tb_search_report.sales_id = tbl_sales.sales_id
GROUP BY search_keyword
```

Just update the above query that will suit your requirements

Comment: I had tried using the INNER JOIN but this query will only returns records which are both present in two tables. That is it will not shows all the records in tb_search_report table.

Comment: Tried LEFT JOIN but the row sale_title returns null values.

Comment: You can change the query to FROM tbl_sales LEFT JOIN tb_search_report ON tbl_sales.sales_id = tb_search_report.sales_id